# Understanding descending intersections of generic extensions

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Let $B_{0}\supseteq B_{1}\supseteq\dots\supseteq B_{\alpha}\supseteq\dots\,\,\left(\alpha<\kappa\right)$ be a descending sequence of complete Boolean algebras,  $B_{\kappa}:=\bigcap_{\alpha<\kappa}B_{\alpha}$, $G_0$ a $V$-generic filter on $B_0$ and for every $\alpha\leq\kappa$, $G_{\alpha}:=G\cap B_{\alpha}$. I want to understand the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha<\kappa}V\left[G_{\alpha}\right]$, which clearly contains $V[G_{\kappa}]$.

In *Iterating ordinal definability*, Zadrożny surveys without proof some results. First are general results:

> 1. (Grigorief) $\bigcap_{\alpha<\kappa}V\left[G_{\alpha}\right]\vDash ZF$
> 2. (Jech) If $B_0$ is $\kappa$-distributive, then $\bigcap_{\alpha<\kappa}V\left[G_{\alpha}\right]=V[G_\kappa]$ (so in particular satisfies $ZFC$)

[The latter appears as lemma 26.6 in the 1978 edition of Jech's Set Theory, but curiously I haven't found it in the 3rd Millennium edition].

Then he gives a more concrete characterization of $V\left[G_{\kappa}\right]$, attributed to Sakarovitch:

> For $p,q\in B_0^+$, let $p\sim q$ iff  $\exists \alpha<\kappa$ such that $$ \inf\{d\in B_\alpha \mid d\geq p\}=\inf\{d\in B_\alpha \mid d\geq q\}$$
>
> Then the separative part of $B_0/{\sim}$ is isomorphic to $B_\kappa^+$.
> In particular, from $G_0$ one can define a $B_0/{\sim}$ generic $G_0/{\sim}$, and if $B_0$ is $\kappa$-distributive then $$\bigcap_{\alpha<\kappa}V\left[G_{\alpha}\right]=V[G_\kappa]=V[G_0/{\sim}]$$

I want to understand this result more, however  Zadrożny references [Sakarovitch's PhD thesis](https://pascal-francis.inist.fr/vibad/index.php?action=getRecordDetail&idt=PASCAL7830080080), which is in French, not available online and as far as I can tell, has no adaptation to a paper. So my questions are:

1. Is there some other source where this result is presented?
2. Can someone provide a proof or at least a sketch?
3. What more can be said on this intersection, given the properties of the descending sequence?

A particular case I'm interested in, is when the sequence is given by "tails" of an iteration (or even product): assume  $\langle P_\alpha \mid\alpha\leq\kappa\rangle$ is an iteration, and set for every $\alpha$ $P_\kappa=P_\alpha * \dot{P}^\alpha$ (so $\dot{P}^\alpha$ is the "tail" of the iteration), and "$B_\alpha=ro(\dot{P}^\alpha)$" (I guess that for this to make perfect sense we should say something like $B_\alpha=ro(P_\kappa)/ro(P_\alpha)$). Can something more concrete be said in this case?

Edit: note that if $P_\kappa$ is  a direct limit (and $\kappa$-distributive), we'd get that all elements are eventually equivalent so $B_0/{\sim}$ is trivial. So on one hand this shows that the intersection is $V$. And on the other hand, the question is interesting only when non-direct limit is taken.

Comment: Regarding your edit: You need to additionally assume that $P_0$ is $\kappa$-distrubutive. Otherwise the intersection can differ from $V$.

Comment: @AndreasLietz yes ofcourse, in my head I was still under that assumption which is present in Sakarovitch's characterization. I'll add it.

Comment: When you say "direct limit", in what sense do you mean this? (I've always found this terminology confusing when it comes to iterations; we have a notion of supports, just tell me the ideal/support system you're using.)

Comment: Also, the result of Grigorieff should probably be in his paper about intermediate models of ZF set theory from 1975 (Annals of Mathematics).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Direct limit here is $<\kappa$-support if I'm not mistaken. And about Grigorief's theorem then yes, that's the source, but I'm more interested in the concrete characterization of Sakarovitch (or any similar analysis in the distributive case)

Comment: So after digging a bit more on Google scholar I managed to find a note by Sakarovitch summarizing the results, which is even in the public domain (although still in French) - https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5619035q/f13.item

Comment: By the way I don't know what is the "separative _part_" of a poset, I've only encountered the "separative _quotient_". I wonder if it's a miss-translation. The original says " le séparé de l'ensemble $B^*$ est isomorphe $B_\kappa^+$". Any french set-theorists around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem should state that the separative *quotient* of $B_{0}/{\sim}$
is isomorphic to $B_{\kappa}^+$.

*Proof.* Recall that the separative quotient of a poset $P$ is the
unique (up to isomorphism) separative $Q$ such that there is an order preserving $h:P\to Q$ such that $x$ is compatible with $y$ iff $h(x)$
is compatible with $h(y)$ (see Jech pg. 205). Since $B_{\kappa}$
is separative as a Boolean algebra, we want to provide such $h:B/{\sim}\to B_{\kappa}^{+}$.

Let $b\in B_{0}^{+}$. For every $\alpha<\kappa$ let
$b_{\alpha}=\inf \{ d\in B_{\alpha}\mid d\geq b \} $,
and let $\bar{b}=\sup\{b_{\alpha}\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$. Note that
$\{b_{\alpha}\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$ is an ascending sequence, so in
fact for every $\beta$, $\bar{b}=\sup\{b_{\alpha}\mid\beta\leq\alpha<\kappa\}$,
and this is an element of $B_{\beta}$, so all-in-all $\bar{b}\in B_{\kappa}$.
Now if $b'\sim b$ then for all large enough $\alpha$, $b_{\alpha}=b_{\alpha}'$
so $\bar{b}=\bar{b'}$. So the function $h([b])=\bar{b}$ is well
defined, and since in particular $\bar{b}\geq b>0$, it is into $B_{\kappa}^{+}$. It is order preserving since if $[b]\leq[c]$ then for all large enough $\alpha$, we have $b_\alpha \leq c_\alpha $ so also $\bar{b}\leq\bar{c}$.

Let $[b],[c]\in B_{0}/{\sim}$. We want to show they are compatible
iff $\bar{b}$ and $\bar{c}$ are compatible.

- If $[b],[c]$ are compatible, $[d]\leq[b],[c]$, then for all large
  enough $\alpha$ $d_{\alpha}\leq b_{\alpha},c_{\alpha}$ so $\bar{d}\leq\bar{b},\bar{c}$.
- If $[b],[c]$ are incompatible, it means that there is an unbounded
  $I\subseteq\kappa$ such that for $\alpha\in I$, $b_{\alpha}$ and
  $c_{\alpha}$ are incompatible. But this also implies that for *every*
  $\alpha,\beta\in I$ $b_{\alpha}$ and $c_{\beta}$ are incompatible
  (if $\alpha<\beta$ and there is e.g. $d\leq b_{\alpha},c_{\beta}$
  then since $b_{\alpha}\leq c_{\beta}$ we get $d\leq b_{\beta},c_{\beta}$),
  so, as we are in a complete Boolean algebra,
  $$
  \overline{b}\cdot\bar{c}=\sum_{\alpha\in I}b_{\alpha}\cdot\sum_{\beta\in I}c_{\beta}=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}b_{\alpha}\cdot c_{\beta}=0
  $$
  i.e. $\bar{b},\overline{c}$ are incompatible. $\square$

Regarding the specific case, my advisor pointed out to me that if we are considering tails of a *full support product*, say of length $\kappa$, then the quotient poset will be $\kappa$-closed.

*Proof sketch.* Let $P=\prod_{\alpha<\kappa}Q_{\alpha}$
be a full support product of posets, and for  $\alpha<\kappa$ let
$P_{\alpha}=\prod_{\alpha\leq\xi<\kappa}Q_{\xi}$. Let $\left\langle p_{i}\mid i<\kappa\right\rangle $ be sequence such
that $i<j$ implies $[p_{i}]>[p_{j}]$. Then to construct $q$ such that $[q]$ is a lower bound, we diagonalize - let $q(\xi)=p_0(\xi)$ until the coordinate witnessing $[p_0]>[p_1]$, then $q(\xi)=p_1(\xi)$ until $p_2$ is smaller, and so on. I'll spare you the indexing monstrosity. $\square$